# where can I find actual implementation of storage tables funtion?

Tags: azure-table-storage

Many samples show table implementation with old deprecreated NUget-package https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-dotnet or cosmos DB tables.

The nuget package shows that it is deprecreated and for azure tables there a  recommended replacement packages (see [Link zu Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) ).

```
WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3 The ID prefix of this package has been reserved for one of the owners of this package by NuGet.org.
Prefix Reserved
This package has been deprecated.
Suggested Alternatives
Azure.Storage.Blobs

Additional Details
Thank you for the interest in this package.

If you are looking for the latest packages to interact with Azure Storage, please use the following libraries:
Azure.Storage.Blobs
Azure.Storage.Queues
Azure.Storage.Blobs.Batch
Azure.Storage.Files.Shares

For older versions of this package see these split packages:
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/9.4.0
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File/9.4.0
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue/9.4.0
```

where i find actual imoplemantation for azure tables?

Answer (score 1):

For working with Storage Tables (or Cosmos Tables), there are 2 packages right now - [`Azure.Data.Tables`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables/) and [`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table). Former is from Azure SDK team while the latter is from Azure Cosmos DB team.

For the former, you can find sample code [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/table/create-table-dotnet?tabs=azure-portal%2Cvisual-studio) (German) and [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cosmos-db/table/create-table-dotnet?tabs=azure-portal%2Cvisual-studio) (English).

Comment: Thanks  I will try it. 
I know this link too but I was irritated  on showing steps for cosmos db first so I thought cosmos DB was necessary for this table access implementation.

Comment: Sorry to less time last weeks . I will try it if I have time. So I have forget it only enough time.